Is there a way to have biometric-only access on Android?
Biometric (fingerprint) authentication can always be bypassed by a PIN. Thieves are asking for the PIN when robbing you, with a gun pointed to your head.
How to make Android secure in this case? Biometric only access is the only way to prevent such problems

Better if they are asking for the pin instead of cutting your fingers off to use them to bypass biometric check. Anyway biometric is bad if you want to encrypt something with it (e.g. Android encrypted user data files). For that purpose you always need a PIN, which means you won't get rid of the pin.

@Robert PIN for unlocking the phone on first boot is different than a PIN to open apps. Android could perfectly support biometrics only for opening apps. iPhone started doing that after news of people getting robbed and asked to annotate their pins. Now you cannot lock someone out of their iCloud account without biometric only and time delay

Looks like it's on Google's roadmap: "Increased authentication to protect you in case your PIN is known by a thief. When enabled, our new enhanced authentication will require biometrics for accessing and changing critical Google account and device settings, like changing your PIN, disabling theft protection or accessing Passkeys, from an untrusted location."
